# How do you get the last star to be only star shown in a rating?

Tags: 7, rating

The out of the box process with fivestar will show star 1,2,3,and 4 highlighted (it will show all stars up to the actual vote). I need stars except the actual vote to be the neutral or the unselected star.

Say for example, someone votes 4 out of 5. How do I show ONLY 4th star highlighted while all the others are either the neutral or unselected star?

EDIT: After reviewing fivestar.js, I believe the code that handles highlighting is the following;

```
$container.find('.star:lt(' + index + ')').addClass('on');
      $container.addClass('fivestar-widget-' + ($options.length));
      $container.find('a')
        .bind('click', $this, Drupal.behaviors.fivestar.rate)
        .bind('mouseover', $this, Drupal.behaviors.fivestar.hover);

      $container.bind('mouseover mouseout', $this, Drupal.behaviors.fivestar.hover);

      // Attach the new widget and hide the existing widget.
      $select.after($container).css('display', 'none');
    });
  },
  rate: function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $widget = event.data;
    var value = this.hash.replace('#', '');
    $('select', $widget).val(value).change();
    var $this_star = $this.closest('.star');
    $this_star.prevAll('.star').andSelf().addClass('on');
    $this_star.nextAll('.star').removeClass('on');
    event.preventDefault();
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fivestar.theme.inc on line 206

```
FROM: elseif ($rating >= $star_value) {

TO: elseif ($rating == $star_value) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Fivestar but if you use [rate](http://drupal.org/project/rate) it has an option to show the users vote. Rate has a fivestar widget as well.

Comment: That wouldn't work as it would still show 4 out of the 5 stars highlighted. I already tried using rate.

Comment: I think you'll have to modify the javascript (rate.js) if you just want to customize the display right after a star has been clicked.

Comment: Until the vote as been submitted. I don't care that the stars would show up (Its actually easier for a user to review their overall review). I need to modify the code once the vote has been cast.